# How to find items located in subfolders?

Tags: macos, finder

I have files that I link images to regularly and now when I go to the main folder location, the finder does not search in the subfolders.

I get the “Name matches” line but it does not find anything.

This is on a Mac Pro using 10.9.5

Comment: Is it trying to search that folder or the whole computer?

Comment: try in Terminal the "mdfind -name yourfilename" if it shows up highlight that line- right click and use Show in Finder to see where it is. I assume that file/folder is not hidden for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

If the folder is excluded from Spotlight, search function in Finder would not work there.